# GRUB not giving any options on partition laptop

Tags: boot, grub2

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 this morning some free space I had partitioned on my Win7 Laptop.

Since then it will only boot into Ubuntu. From all the other posts I've seen it appears to usually be the other way around. I would be far more comfortable keeping and using linux if I knew that I could get back to windows should I need to.

Grub does not present me with any options. The bootinfoscript now returns the following, as I have spent some time trying to make sure i have a menu.lst file and the boot disk )
sda1)

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks
    in partition 112 for .
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:
    Boot files:

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda5 starts
                       at sector 2048.
    Operating System:
    Boot files:
sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/menu.lst /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /boot/bcd

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:
    Boot files:
```

Edit -
ran os-prober and came back with the following results
/dev/sda2:Windows Recovery Environment (loader):Windows:chain
/dev/sda4:Windows Recovery Environment (loader):Windows1:chain

I've run the boot-repair and I now have grub giving me the options for Ubuntu or Windows recovery environment.

I have a partition for boot, 1 for windows,  1 which was used for storage and then 1 for a virtual machine.

Running both os-prober  and then sudo grub-mkconfig comes back with the below. I've managed to get the Window Repair environment onto the Grub loader, but it still wont let me boot into Windows. Even the Windows recovery disk isn't letting me in.

```
phil@WrenCrescent:~$ sudo os-prober
/dev/sda2:Windows Recovery Environment (loader):Windows:chain
/dev/sda4:Windows Recovery Environment (loader):Windows1:chain
phil@WrenCrescent:~$ sudo grub-mkconfig
Generating grub configuration file ...
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos6'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  7d8f76ab-c8ce-4f92-9714-38e283ea84c6
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7d8f76ab-c8ce-4f92-9714-38e283ea84c6
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_GB
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-7d8f76ab-c8ce-4f92-9714-38e283ea84c6' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  7d8f76ab-c8ce-4f92-9714-38e283ea84c6
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7d8f76ab-c8ce-4f92-9714-38e283ea84c6
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=7d8f76ab-c8ce-4f92-9714-38e283ea84c6 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-7d8f76ab-c8ce-4f92-9714-38e283ea84c6' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-advanced-7d8f76ab-c8ce-4f92-9714-38e283ea84c6' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  7d8f76ab-c8ce-4f92-9714-38e283ea84c6
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7d8f76ab-c8ce-4f92-9714-38e283ea84c6
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=7d8f76ab-c8ce-4f92-9714-38e283ea84c6 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-recovery-7d8f76ab-c8ce-4f92-9714-38e283ea84c6' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  7d8f76ab-c8ce-4f92-9714-38e283ea84c6
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7d8f76ab-c8ce-4f92-9714-38e283ea84c6
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=7d8f76ab-c8ce-4f92-9714-38e283ea84c6 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda2
menuentry 'Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-1670675A7067401B' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos2  1670675A7067401B
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1670675A7067401B
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda4
menuentry 'Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda4)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-58DEB964DEB93B58' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos4  58DEB964DEB93B58
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 58DEB964DEB93B58
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
done
```

Comment: Edit the question and add the output of `sudo os-prober` and `sudo grub-mkconfig`.

Comment: It looks like your boot record may be extended across a couple partitions. This could cause problems if it was overwritten. I could be wrong though. You have 7 partitions when running normally?

Comment: I had 2 partitions as far as i was aware, with a third which was for a virtual machine. 2 for Linux. I think that there are then 2 which was being used for booting. If this is the case, anybody got any ideas what to do?

Comment: Sorry for the huge file and the capitals and bold. I don't mean to come across as rude, just not sure who to take them off when pasting from a file.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7394793/

Comment: If sda2 is your Windows install you need boot flag or active partition on sda2. Then Windows repairs can fix sda2 if fixes needed. Grub2's os-prober finds NTFS partitions with bootmgr & BCD as bootable, but may not always say just Windows or recovery. It for whatever reason mixes them up. Then try booting the sda2 entry in grub menu.

Comment: Do you know what partition 112 means in this context?  I thought my grub was on partition /dev/sda3.  Does 112 somehow mean /dev/sda3?

Answer (score 1):

So I finally found a resolution to this. Might help anyone else having the same problem.

My Windows operating system required repairing, and although I could not find the original installation disc for my model of Win 7, I was able to find one. I used that to boot, and also have a "press f4 for recovery" mode on my Bios. Both together finally allowed me to do a windows repair.

After that os-prober was actually able to discover windows, so I used boot-repair and now have the options that I want

Done and done.